# Why does t+=i+'a' give the correct output while t=t+i+'a' gives an error?

Tags: c++, string

I have been working on some question that involves converting ASCII value into string.

If I use this code, I get output as `g`, which is expected.

```cpp
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=6; vector<string> ans;
    string t= "";

    t+=i+'a';

    ans.push_back(t);
    cout<<ans[0];
    return 0;
}
```

However, If I change the code like this:

```cpp
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=6; vector<string> ans;
    string t= "";

    t=t+i+'a';        // <----

    ans.push_back(t);
    cout<<ans[0];

    return 0;
}
```

The following error is shown, when I try to compile it:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} and 'int')

7 | t=t+i+'a';
  |   ~^~
  |   | |
  |   | int
  |   std::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}
```

The only difference between both the code is that in 1st code, I am using `t+=i+'a';`, while in second, `t=t+i+'a';` is used.

Can someone please tell what is wrong with the second snippet?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245504/discussion-on-question-by-anuj-why-does-tia-give-the-correct-output-while-t).

Answer (score 11):

**1. The `t += i + 'a';` case**

Here, two things are important. *First*,

```
std::string& std::string::operator+=(char ch);
```

is called, which is a **non-template member function** of the `std::string` class (that is, of the `std::basic_string<char>` class template instance); see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D.

*Second*, the type of `i + 'a'` is `int`.

Everything works fine, since the argument `i + 'a'` of type `int` can be used as an argument for a function parameter of type `char`.

**2. The `t = t + i + 'a';` case**

In contrast to case 1., `operator+` is used here. First for the `t + i` part, where `i` is of type `int` (see @AnoopRana's answer for details of why). But `opeartor+` is a **free (non-member) function template**; see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B.

The compiler tries to instantiate this definition:

```
template<class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc>
std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>
operator+( const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& lhs, CharT rhs );
```

But it can't since:

1. according to the first argument of type `std::string`, `CharT` would be deduced as `char`,
2. according to the second argument of type `int`, `CharT` would be deduced as `int`.

Therefore, *duduction conflict* happens. And, there is no other template that might be instantiated.

---

Simple demo code of the same problem:

```
template <typename Char>
struct String
{
    String& operator+=(Char);
};

template <typename Char>
String<Char> operator+(const String<Char>&, Char);

int main()
{
    String<char> s;
    s += 2 + 'a';
    s = s + 2 + 'a';
}
```

Live link: https://godbolt.org/z/MonK1e3bq

Comment: IMO answer covers most important part of problem, but ignores operator precedence and demo of working equivalent version:  https://godbolt.org/z/hPGGMhP6r

Comment: @MarekR Well, operator precedence isn't really important here, we can reproduce the issue *without* the `+ 'a'`: https://godbolt.org/z/c7anTed1d . Note, though, that they say: *"`operator+` is used here, **first for the `t + i` part**, where `i` is of type `int`."*.

Comment: @Bob__ Your claim that *"operator precednece isn't really important here"* is incorrect. When parsing an expression operator precedence is very important. In particular, in your demo you have `s = s + 2;` which is grouped as `s = (s + 2);` and not `(s = s) + 2;` due to operator precedence and then only other things happen. Similarly operator precedence is also used in parsing `t=t+i+'a';`. So it is very important to the problem even though the problem can be reproduced by writing `t=t+(i+'a');` that doesn't mean operator precedence isn't part of the problem.

Comment: Continued... In case 1 also `t+=i+'a';` is grouped as `t+=(i+'a');` and not `(t+=i)+'a';`.

Comment: @AnoopRana Can we agree that the order is important to obtain the *expected result*, but it's not to *reproduce the error* (see e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/rxKjvbP3s)?

Comment: I suspect neither consruct gives OP what they want, and maybe they should use a `stringstream` instead.

Answer (score -1):

The **problem** in case 2 is that the statement `t = t + i + 'a'` is actually grouped as(or equivalent to) `t = (t + i) + 'a'` due to **operator precedence**.

```
//---v---v--------->t is std::string while i is an int
t = (t + i) + 'a'; //equivalent to this due to operator precedence
```

Now as `t` is a `std::string` and `i` is an `int` and since there is no overloaded `operator+` that takes an `std::string` and a `int`, we get the mentioned error.

---

Note that `+` is an arithmetic operator and so in the first case, the character literal `'a'` is **promoted** to `int` when writing `i + 'a'`. And since `std::string` has the [overload](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/) `string& string::operator+= (char)` that can be used, the first case uses that overloaded `operator+=`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245505/discussion-on-answer-by-anoop-rana-why-does-tia-give-the-correct-output-whi).